# Specific Android Popup Menu

Tags: android, menu, popupmenu

I am familiar with the Android PopupMenu ability, but I want a popup that looks like this:[image]

Comment: Please take a little time to read the [FAQ's](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) (again, if you have already done so). SO is not a site where you ask solutions for what you need done. If you were mislead into thinking that, you were perhaps looking for a www.freelancer.com or something.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just a heads up, the Android Developers site (http://developer.android.com/index.html) has all of this explained in detail with tutorials.  Try this:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

builder.setTitle(title);

builder.setItems(new CharSequence[] {"Copy Text", "Delete", "Details"} , 
    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() 
    {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) { /* which is an index */ } 
    }); 
builder.show();
```

Comment: This worked.  I just had to add: builder.show();

Comment: Is there a way to change the color to white like in the photo?

Comment: I figured it out: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.html

Comment: I revised the answer. Good luck on your project.